# Dev console to generate PDF - Not using VF/Lightning at all

Tags: apex

I am trying to insert a dummy document from dev console and attachment gets inserted  but its throwing me the error of **Failed to open the document** when i try to view the document.

```
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    Blob body;
    attach.contentType = 'application/pdf';
    body=blob.valueOf('TestString');
    attach.Body = body;
    attach.Name = 'testPDF.pdf';
    attach.IsPrivate = false;
    attach.ParentId = '0036F00002f7478';
    insert attach;
```

Comment: Try with `ContentType` proprty value set to pdf content type.

Comment: I have it and its  still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer :) I just mimicked the HTML format and it worked.

```
String HTMLS = '<HTML><BODY>'; //Start of HTML
String HTMLE = '</BODY></HTML>'; // End of HTML
String pdfContent = '' + HTMLS ;
pdfContent = pdfContent + 'Here goes the MAIN CONTENT' ;
pdfContent = pdfContent + HTMLE ;
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
Blob body;
attach.contentType = 'application/pdf';
attach.Body = blob.toPdf(pdfContent);
attach.Name = system.now()+'.pdf';
attach.IsPrivate = false;
attach.ParentId = '0036F00002fM7aQ';
insert attach;
```

Answer (score 3):

PDF is a specific file format. You can't just put random bytes into a file and call it a PDF. You'll get the error you specified on most platforms. Instead, you need a valid PDF, such as generating one from a website:

```
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
Blob body;
attach.contentType = 'application/pdf';
body= new ApexPages.PageReference('https://www.google.com/').getContentAsPDF();
attach.Body = body;
attach.Name = 'testPDF.pdf';
attach.IsPrivate = false;
attach.ParentId = '0036F00002f7478';
insert attach;
```

You don't need Visualforce, if you use `ApexPages.PageReference#getContentAsPDF`. You do, however, need a valid PDF file if you want to generate a PDF file.

Comment: **ApexPages.PageReference#getContentAsPDF** How do i use this with the test string which i have? 
This is throwing me **internal salesforce error**

Comment: @Arvind You can't. It has to be a real resource somewhere. You can't use an arbitrary string. There's no mechanism for that anywhere in Apex.

Comment: (unless you make your own VF page, and pass that string as a parameter there in a URL and render it only)

Comment: This can be a html format. 
Thanks both @sfdcfox  and kurunve